# перенос из одной таблицы в дургую

Tags: php, mysql

Всем доброго времени суток! Помогите, пожалуйста с mysql

Есть 2 таблицы `jpa` и `players`

В таблице `jpa` есть столбцы `user_id` и `map` 
В таблице `players` есть точно такие же столбцы.

Помогите написать скрипт, который при замене значения `map` в таблице `jpa` будет менять его и в таблице `players`

Answer (score 1):

просто отправляешь базе апдейт запрос сразу для двух таблиц

```
UPDATE jpa, players
SET jpa.map = 'new', players.map = 'new'
WHERE jpa.user_id = 1 and players.user_id = 1
```

Comment: мне не нужно одновременно. У меня есть скрипт, который определяет на какой карте будет проводиться бой заранее, и в определенное время мне нужно все значения с jpa перенести в players, соответственно id пользователей

Comment: Тогда просто в определенный момент выбери нужные значения
SELECT user_id, map FROM jpa
занеси их в массивы $user_id[] и $map[], а потом в цикле перебирай значения и формируй запрос
for ($i=0; $i<count($user_id);$i++){
     $query = 'UPDATE players SET map='.$map[$i].' WHERE 'user_id='.$user_id[$i];
}

Answer (score 0):

Может быть кому то будет полезно:

```
$mapJPA = $mysqli->query("SELECT `user_id`, `map` FROM `jpa` WHERE 1");

while ($row = $mapJPA->fetch_assoc()) {
    $mysqli->query("UPDATE `server_1_players` SET `mapId` = ".$row['map']." WHERE `userID` = ".$row['user_id']);
}
```